# Label tag wrapping Input tag in radio buttons (Simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using the gem simple_form with Rails to create my forms.

I want to create radio_buttons that have the input tag wrapped in the label tag, for example:

```
<label>
  <input id="optionsRadios2" name="optionsRadios" value="option2" type="radio"/>
  Option one
</label>
```

but what I get is this:

```
<input id="optionsRadios" name="optionsRadios" value="option2" type="radio"/>
<label for="optionsRadios1"> Option one</label>
```

Is there a way to create the input tag inside label tag using wrappers? how?

I could not find any ways by now (here is the doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_radio_buttons)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :optionsRadios1, :optionsRadios2, {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "radio-inline" }%>
```

Comment: No sorry, that's the standard way. Input and Label tags are separed. Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroDS Show your code.. so that we can fix it there.. From which code you got the unexpected html.. show us

Comment: @AlessandroDS did you tried my update answer with {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'}, {:class => "radio-inline" } added ?

Comment: @R_O_R the line of code in Adnan's message used is a good code example. Yes I tried {:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'} , it is just to put the radios in the same line, nothing about nesting input with label. I think I found the solution: it's in the doc, you can pass a block to collection_radio_buttons, I am experimenting with that. I'll put an update about it.

Comment: @AdnanDevops, is there a way to remove the `item_wrapper_class` argument and only use the `class`?  It doesn't seem like it's optional.  If I remove that from my statement the class seems to get ignored.