# Reder class for a collection_radio_buttons within simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using simple_form to create a form within my Rails project.

```
<%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post, id: 'invitations-form', class: 'invitations-form'} do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :first_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's First Name", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40, value: nil } %>

      <%= f.input :last_name, label: false, placeholder: "Family Member's Last", input_html: { maxlength: 15, size: 40, value: nil } %>

      <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Enter Email Address", input_html: { value: nil } %>

      <div class="radio_buttons">
      <%= f.label "#{:gender}:"%>
      <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [["male", "male"] ,["female", "female"]], :first, :last %>
      </div>

      <%= f.input :invitation_relation, label: false, prompt: "I am this person's:", collection: relation_types, label_method: :humanize, input_html: { class: "browser-default dropmodule__input-select" } %>

      <%= submit_tag "Send Invitation" %>
  <% end %>
```

I have used the collection_radio_buttons method to create, well, a collection of radio buttons.  I'm not sure this is relevant, but the reason I used this method instead of `f.input :foo,  as: :radio_buttons` was due to the fact that the input method wasn't producing a label tag for me, which I think I could now produce using `label_html`.  I'm not sure if this would be a viable alternative, but this bug is bothersome to me due to the time I've spent on it.

Here's the html generated output for the relevant div above:

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <label class="string optional control-label" for="user_gender:">Gender:</label>
  <span>
    <input checked="checked" id="user_gender_male" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="male">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_male">male</label>
  </span>
  <span>
    <input id="user_gender_female" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="female">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_female">female</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need the input tag for each radio_button to contain a class of "with-gap", like so:

```
<input checked="checked" id="user_gender_male" class="with-gap" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="male">
```

and

```
<input id="user_gender_female" class="with-gap" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="female">
```

but I have been unsuccessful.  Although I really want to solve the issue by placing the class within the label of the collection_radio_buttons method, if there is an alternative within simple_form please show this as a solution.

Comment: Have you tried ```label_html: { class: 'with-gap' }``` ?

Comment: Yes, I actually made a mistake on my description.  I need to show the class within the input tag, but I've tried `input_html { class: "with-gap" }` and it ignores me.`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30619068/4379077

What I needed to do was add an `item_wrapper_class` as the 5th argument to the method.  It doesn't look like it's optional.  When I try to remove it from the argument list my class argument (the 6th arg in the method) gets ignored.  Here's the final input:

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <%= f.label "#{:gender}:"%>
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [["male", "male"] ,["female", "female"]], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'foo-bar'}, {:class => "with-gap" } %>
</div>
```

and final output:

```
<div class="radio_buttons">
  <label class="string optional control-label" for="user_gender:">Gender:</label>
  <span class="foo-bar">
    <input checked="checked" class="with-gap" id="user_gender_male" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="male">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_male">male</label >
  </span>
  <span class="foo-bar">
    <input class="with-gap" id="user_gender_female" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="female">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_gender_female">female</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

If anyone knows how to make the `inline_wrapper_class` optional please let me know.